# spring custome events:how to raise an event whenever a property values changed in spring bean

Tags: java, spring

Can you please help me how to write the code for following scenario:

I have a class called A

```
class A 
{
    private int a;
    private String name;
    private status;

    //setters and getters
}
```

If(any property values changed) then raise an event (for suppose PropertyChangeEvent)
then execute the logic in class B...

```
class B 
{
    someLogic() {}
}
```

Comment: an easy way would be to use setters for the fields in A which call B.someLogic().

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's `PropertyChangeLister` to implement this. Please take a look at Vogel's tutorial on [Observer Design Pattern in Java](http://www.vogella.com/articles/DesignPatternObserver/article.html).